# Determine Android N preview stage build

Tags: developer-preview, 7.0-nougat

I have Nexus 6P and I'm on Android Beta Program for Android N Developer Preview. From [its program overview](http://developer.android.com/preview/overview.html), it's stated that there will be 6 stages:

1. Preview 1 (initial release, alpha)
2. Preview 2 (incremental update, beta)
3. Preview 3 (incremental update, beta)
4. Preview 4 (final APIs and official SDK, Play publishing)
5. Preview 5 (near-final system images for final testing)
6. Final release to AOSP and ecosystem

How do I know which Android N preview stage I have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android provides release notes for Android N Developer Preview on [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20160822092118/https://developer.android.com/preview/support.html) (as of current writing):

1. Developer Preview 1
   Date: March 2016
   **Builds: NPC56P, NPC56R, updated: NPC56W, NPC56X**
2. Developer Preview 2
   Date: April 2016
   **Builds: NPC91K, NPC91O**
3. Developer Preview 3
   Date: May 2016
   **Builds: NPD35K**
4. Developer Preview 4
   Date: June 2016
   **Builds: NPD56N**
5. Developer Preview 5
   Date: July 2016
   **Builds: NPD90G**

You can compare your build number with the available release notes by going to **Settings - About phone - Build number**.

Comment: I thought I got Developer Preview 2 this morning and wanted to verify. But the build number is NPC56W, so that means I have Developer Preview 1 but updated. Thanks.